# Does C have templates?

Tags: c, templates, parallel-processing, cilk-plus

I've previously worked with C but I'm still a major newby in general.
Currently I'm working on a little project that involves Parallel Computing and for this we are using the language Cilk+.

My objective is to implement a parallel scan pattern using Cilk+ and I've found this reference to the subject, but I don't understand half of the notations on it.

Does C have templates? I thought only C++ had them.

If yes, how do they work? I've found nothing regarding the subject.

If not, then can someone explain me what line 1 and 5 mean?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What makes you believe the code you're looking at *is* written in C?

Comment: Line 1 and 5 simply mean that this is not C code.

Comment: Please don't paste images of code. Include the code itself in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not have templates. C++ does.

Line 1 is using C++ templates.

Line 5 is not standard C or C++. It is part of the Cilk Plus extension.

If this is a new project, you may way to avoid Cilk Plus. It's officially deprecated. [Intel is encouraging everyone to switch to OpenMP or TBB instead.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/migrate-your-application-to-use-openmp-or-intelr-tbb-instead-of-intelr-cilktm-plus?_ga=2.82595986.561933432.1543369164-394789281.1543369164)